# Recursive loop for 11 "min or max" variables

Tags: excel, vba

it's been a while since I coded much in VBA so getting myself tangled in the loops.

I have a table (B3:E14) which I want to loop through to return all permutations, placing them one by one in the final column ("Test"), where I'll run some other code, then transpose that test column into a row of results with variables as columns.

| Variable | Min | Max | Test |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | 5 | 6 | i |
| Bananas | 2.5 | 3.5 | j |
| Oranges | -2 | -1 | k |

Does that make sense?

So my final table might look something like...

| Run | Apples | Bananas | Oranges | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2.5 | -2 |  |
| 2 | 6 | 2.5 | -2 |  |
| 3 | 5 | 3.5 | -2 |  |
| 4 | 5 | 2.5 | -1 |  |
| etc |  |  |  |  |
| 2048 | 6 | 3.5 | -1 |  |

Darren

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do that.

You should check out this article, about different loops in VBA, you'll get your answers here.

https://trumpexcel.com/vba-loops/

Here you can find some examples about looping through a table.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, hebet0o, I've had a read through and couldn't see anything directly relevant. I think I was hoping someone might be able to show something here directly?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).